# Case in where clause

Tags: sql

```
SELECT * FROM O_PLATI_DAUNE
WHERE 
     LUNA LIKE     
CASE
   WHEN LUNA = '7'  THEN SUMA ='363623.72'
   WHEN LUNA = '8'  THEN SUMA ='825159.25'
   WHEN LUNA = '9'  THEN SUMA ='182730.99'
   WHEN LUNA = '10' THEN SUMA ='361722.74'
   WHEN LUNA = '11' THEN SUMA ='1787574.67'
   WHEN LUNA = '12' THEN SUMA ='3605005.68'
ELSE 'N/A'
END
```

I don't know why it doesn't work, please somebody help me!

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Caps lock, on the left, just under "tab".

Comment: What is your error/problem? Are you trying to do a LIKE CASE ? What server are you using as well?

Comment: what error do you get please?

Comment: @nick - why don't you just edit it?

Comment: @Preet - On a question like this it'll get overwritten, check out the revision history to see this has already happened: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/3830380/revisions I tend to wait a few minutes to do any meaningful edit on one so surely to be edited by others.  Also, just fixing the user's questions every time does nothing to help them ask better ones in the future.

Comment: Are you trying to change the value of a column in the output ? If so you don't want that in the where clause. Please clarify what your goal is.

Comment: This query makes no sense at all. Can you explain in words what you are trying to do? (with capslock off!)

Comment: @Nick - but sarky commenting does? Oh ok.

Comment: @Preet - It's called humor, if you can't find a problem immediately you might as well find humor in it to stay sane...if you can't do that with even the "drive-by" question, well....not sure what to say there.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to do something like:

```
SELECT id,LUNA,CASE
   WHEN LUNA = '7'  THEN '363623.72'
   WHEN LUNA = '8'  THEN '825159.25'
   WHEN LUNA = '9'  THEN '182730.99'
   WHEN LUNA = '10' THEN '361722.74'
   WHEN LUNA = '11' THEN '1787574.67'
   WHEN LUNA = '12' THEN '3605005.68'
   ELSE 'N/A'
   END as SUMA
 FROM O_PLATI_DAUNE
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is for MySQL, so I would recommend reading the manual on CASE:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/case-statement.html

Look at the example a little further down the page - your case structure is off.

Case statements can't be used directly in the WHERE clause - trying to find an example, but no luck thus far.